# Copy and paste value to another worksheet by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to work on VBA to copy and paste some cell values to the other worksheets in the same workbook.

In *Order List* worksheet format is as follows:

```
(Column A)   | (Column B)          | (Column C) | (Column D) | (Column E) | (Column F)
Product Code | Product Description | Price      | Quantity   | Net Amount | Sheet Name
```

I need to copy the *Quantity* in *Order List* sheet and paste to relevant sheet as shown in Column F.

For example, *Product Code* AAA has *Quantity* 10 with *Sheet Name* Art in *Order List*.

```
Product Code | Product Description | Price | Quantity | Net Amount | Sheet Name 
AAA            ...                   ...     5          ...          Art
```

I need a code to replace AAA's *Quantity* (Column G) in *Art* sheet to 10 instead of 5. The *Product Code* is in Column B of *Art* Sheet.

```
(Column B)   | ...           | (Column G)
Product Code | Other headers | Quantity
AAA            ...             10           ' <---- REPLACE WITH 5
```

I have updated as following:

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long

j = 18

With Worksheets("Order List")

If Sheets("Order List").Range("F" & j) <> "" And Sheets("Order List").Range("A" & j) <> "" Then

 i = Worksheets(.Range("F" & j)).Columns("B").Find(What:=.Range("A" & j).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

Sheets("Order List").Range("D" & j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(Worksheets("Order List").Range("F" & j)).Range("G" & i)

j = j + 1

End If
```

There is no error message now, but not replace the quantity either in Art Sheet.
Is the destination wrong? Could you please double check it for me? Many thanks

Comment: You don't need to find a value for `j` unless the relevant sheet and the product code are both available, so don't try to use those values before you check that they are available.

Comment: @YowE3K I have updated the columns. Product Code in Column A, Quantity in Column D and Sheet Name is in Column F in Order List. The first row is 18 in Order List. Product Codes are in Column B in the other worksheets. I understand that the code you wrote is find the row number and I use this row number to find the relevant Column G in the other sheets (Art Sheet in this example). The relevant sheet and the product code are both available, so I assume the code should work. I have updated it and still see run time error "9". Could you please correct my code if it is wrong? Many thanks

Comment: Your updated code is still trying to use `Worksheets(.Range("F" & j))` before you test whether `Sheets("Order List").Range("F" & j) <> ""`.  So if it is blank, you are looking for the worksheet with no name.  Don't try to use the values before you check that they are available - move the calculation of `i` **inside** the `If` statement where you will know that it will work.

Comment: @YowE3K I have updated it again as your advice. Hope I didn't misunderstand you. It is now showing Type Mismatch. Would you mind checking it again for me please? Many thanks

Comment: It looks like this is one of the cases where the `Value` property is not used by default - `.Range("F" & j)` needs to be changed to `.Range("F" & j).Value` when being used as an index to the `Worksheets` collection.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you so much for your help. It is working now.

Comment: @YowE3K Sorry, but it still has a tinny problem. It is only copy the line 18 quantity and paste to Art Sheet, but not the rest of lines in Order List.

Comment: If you want to perform that code in a loop, you will need to include a loop.  (I would recommend a `For j = 18 To whatever` loop, but there are a lot of different ways to do it, so you should choose the method you are most comfortable with.)  If you have trouble implementing a loop, raise another question. (It will probably get closed as a "duplicate" because there are **lots** of answers here on Stack Overflow that show how to loop through the rows in a worksheet, but at least that will save you searching for an answer.)

Comment: Great. I have used For To Loop and it works perfect. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Find` command, i.e. something like:

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long

j = 18

With Worksheets("Order List")
    If .Range("F" & j).Value <> "" And .Range("A" & j).Value <> "" Then
        i = Worksheets(.Range("F" & j).Value).Columns("B").Find(What:=.Range("A" & j).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
        .Range("D" & j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(.Range("F" & j).Value).Range("G" & i)
        'or, if you just want to copy the value, use
        'Worksheets(.Range("F" & j).Value).Range("G" & i).Value = .Range("D" & j).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
End With
```

Notes:

1. Assumes product code is in column A of the sheet you are trying to update.
2. This will crash if the product code does not exist in column A of the relevant sheet.  If that is a possibility then you will need to include the proper error checking to see whether the `Find` was successful (i.e. did not return `Nothing`) before attempting to get the `Row` property.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated the code. However, I still have some error here. Could you please take a look again for me?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is an easier, alternate solution.  Instead of handling the troublesome multi-sheet order quantity search with VBA (and *"putting"* the new data on the order sheet), you could use the more-user-friendly worksheet Lookup function(s) on the Order List worksheet to *"get"* the data consolidated in one place from all the other sheets, and then a simple single column copy & paste when the time is right.

[image: sample destination sheet]

and

[[image: sample data[2]]

You can download my [simple] demo XLSM [from JumpShare here](http://jmp.sh/M6Zqg3h) to demonstrate what I mean by "put instead of get".  Basically 1 lookup formula does all the searching for you, only 2 lines of code to copy over new data when required.  {Note that the macro won't work on the online viewer.)

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not my forte, so I deconstructed your code a bit into the following so I could understand it better.

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long
Dim s As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

j = 18
Set ws = Worksheets("Order List")

s = ws.Range("A" & j).Value
i = Worksheets(ws.Range("F" & j)).Columns("B").Find(What:=s, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

If ws.Range("F" & j) <> "" And ws.Range("A" & j) <> "" Then
  ws.Range("D" & j).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("F" & j).Range("G" & i)
  j = j + 1
End If
```

The one thing that jumped out at me was the last real line of code:

```
Destination:=Worksheets("F" & j).Range("G" & i)
```

This tells me there is a **worksheet** in your workbook named "Fx" (where x is a number).  Is it possible you meant this?

```
Destination:=Worksheets(ws.Range("F" & j))
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have changed worksheet as Worksheet.Range instead. Many thanks